# Heat transfer of a wire

Tags: thermodynamics

I'am trying to heat up a wire with a current. When calculating the heat transfer of the wire, I need an expression for $\displaystyle{\frac{dT}{dx}}$. How do I express this?

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Please provide a bit more context and details for your question. As of now, it is hard to tell what situation exactly you are trying to model with the heat equation(?!).

Comment: What   is   $x$ ????

Comment: Google convection heat transfer from cylinder or cylindrical fins.

Answer (score 1):

Heating of the wire via current counts as internal heat generation .You can check the derivation for heat transfer in the radial direction for a cylinder with internal heat generation.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to heat up a wire with electrical current, there is no heat transfer from one end to another end, thus no need for $\frac {dT}{dx}$. The heat is produced along the line by the current.